# How to change MaterialCommunityIcons to my own icon React Native // TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

Im beginner in react native and I would like to use my own icon:

***(assets/user.png)***

Just exchange MaterialCommunityIcons to my own. React Native 5.x

But I have no idea how to do this...

Here's code:

```
        <Tab.Navigator
                           activeColor="#3e2465"
                           inactiveColor="#8366ae"
                           barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#f1eded' }}
            >
                <Tab.Screen name="Home"
                            component={Map}
                            options={{
                                tabBarLabel: 'Map',
                                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="map" color={color} size={26} />
                                    ),
                            }}
                />
                <Tab.Screen name="Login"
                            component={EventList}
                            options={{
                                tabBarLabel: 'EventList',
                                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cup" color={color} size={26} />
                                    ),
                            }}
                />
                <Tab.Screen name="Logi1n"
                            component={Profile}
                            options={{
                                tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
                                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-box-outline" color={color} size={26} />
                                    ),
                            }}
                />
            </Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: u can use and <Image> for that

Answer (score 0):

just replace the return component from the tab icon function with image component with your asset as src like

```js
        <Tab.Navigator
                           activeColor="#3e2465"
                           inactiveColor="#8366ae"
                           barStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#f1eded' }}
            >
                <Tab.Screen name="Home"
                            component={Map}
                            options={{
                                tabBarLabel: 'Map',
                                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                                    //<MaterialCommunityIcons name="map" color={color} size={26} />
                               //just replace your material community icons with

                              <Image src={.../path/to/your/asset/file} style={{height:30, width:30}} tintColor={color}/>
                                    ),
                            }}
                />
                ...
            </Tab.Navigator>
```